Can anyone help me with a FileNotFoundError?
I have exhausted gemini, trying to figure out why i am receiving an error message while trying to pickle a ML model for a data project. I would appreciate any advice that someone can give me. I have the correct file path. I don't know if it is a cloud issue, but i moved the folder to my local device and it is still giving me the error message.
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/michael/Google_rf/hr_rf1.pickle'
this is the function i am trying to use ....
def write_pickle(path, model_object, save_as:str):
with open(path + save_as + ".pickle", "wb") as to_write:
pickle.dump(model_object, to_write)
and i put my file path in before the function ..
path = "/Users/michael/Google_rf/"
then i called it like this .....
write_pickle(path, rf1, 'hr_rf1')
I switched the folder over to my local drive. I made sure the jupyter notebook kernal was set for python. I checked the spelling and confirmed the file path, etc..

Please read and follow How do I ask a good question?. In particular, there is a section 'Help others reproduce the problem'. That will lead you to How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example that covers formatting your code as code blocks we can use. You'd see your code is unusable if you took the advice at the bottom of the guide: "Try reproducing the problem yourself, in a fresh environment and make sure you can do so using only the information included in your question."

As to your issue, first try writing to the current working directory. Then if that works use pwd run in cells in your notebook to see where you are in your file hierarchy and then use %cd to change the working directory and use ls to see what is in the current directory. Then using those, troubleshoot what your notebook can see and demonstrate in your post to us about the presence of /Users/michaelsabatino/Google_rf/. Also, did you try path = r"/Users/michaelsabatino/Google_rf/"?

You need to format your code to make it more readable. Make sure python is running from the directory you think it is.
In your script you can simply add
import os
print(os.getcwd())

to view the actual directory you are running in. From there you can update your path as necessary.

Thank you. You helped me figure it out. This was the problem ..../home/jovyan/work is a common default working directory in Jupyter Notebook environments, particularly in cloud-based platforms like Google Colab or JupyterHub.
